# redux-thunk - not dispatching even though I used mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a weird problem with my redux action.

I have two functions A(), B() inside the same component which call an action function ac() that uses a thunk to do async call to the server.

I used mapDispatchToprops to map ac() to the component.

When I invoke A() it works like a charm, the action is dispatched and state is updated. But if I invoke B() which invokes the same ac() in the same way the action is not dispatched. It is as if I am calling a normal function so the thunk inside is not executed.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: generateAgreement() works but signAgreement() doesn't, even though they call the same action updateAgreements()

```
generateAgreement = async evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const selectedAgreement = this.props.myAgreements[evt.target.id];

    this.props.updateAgreements(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        {
          myAgreements: this.props.myAgreements,
          selectedAgreement
        }
      ),
      this.props.user.token,
      "generate-agreement",
      {
        agreementId: selectedAgreement.id
      },
      actionTypes.GENERATE_AGREEMENT
    );
  };

  signAgreement = async evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const selectedAgreement = this.props.myAgreements[evt.target.id];

    this.props.updateAgreements(
      Object.assign(
        {},
        {
          myAgreements: this.props.myAgreements,
          selectedAgreement
        }
      ),
      this.props.user.token,
      "sign-agreement",
      {
        agreementId: selectedAgreement.id
      },
      actionTypes.SIGN_AGREEMENT
    );
  };
```

Comment: Post code, something must be different between how A and B are called

Comment: @RayWiis posted the code. Thanks!

Comment: Seems alright if the `this` is not bound to something else, but that would just give you an error when you call the action. There might be something surrounding this, not sure...

Comment: Added some console statements first function's action prints `ƒ () {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, arguments));
  }` second function's action prints `({
  myAgreements
}, token, api_url, reqBody, action_type) => async dispatch => {
  console.debug("executing update");

  try {
    const result = await axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.p…` Don't know why the other function's action is becoming a plain function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. This is one of the classic examples to avoid using object destructuring all over the place.

In my case, in my parent component 1 I imported from the `actions.js` file as follows:

**Component_1.js**

```
import { updateAgreements } from "../redux/actions.js"

...

render() {
    return <Child 
        updateAgreements={updateAgreements}
    />
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
   updateAgreements
}
...
```

And in parent component 2 I have the following code which is the reason generateAgreement worked as expected:

**Component_2.js**

```
import { updateAgreements } from "../redux/actions.js"

...

render() {\
    const { updateAgreements } = this.props;
    return <Child 
        updateAgreements={updateAgreements}
    />
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
   updateAgreements
}
...
```

Notice that in component_1 `updateAgreements` is taken from the import statement and in component_2 it is taken from the props.

I have seen a lot of people warning about overusing destructuring now I see how it can cause subtle bugs like this.